# How to perform locale based sorting while using hibernate as ORM

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, internationalization

I use server based sorting(in the db) using orderby clause. But now that I want to support multiple locales,  how should I pass the locale information to the DB via hibernate layer. I  have pre-defined views to which I add criteria and order in the hibernate layer.

Answer (score 1):

> But now that I want to support multiple locales, how should I pass the locale information to the DB via hibernate layer.

Honestly, I'm not sure I understood exactly what you want to do but if you want to order by something in a query, that something should obviously be present at the database level. Maybe you could elaborate a bit or illustrate what you want to achieve with an example?

Just in case, here are some resources that might give some inspiration:

- How to use a [Collection of Elements](http://i-proving.com/space/Technologies/Hibernate/Hibernate+Annotation+Examples/Collection+of+Elements) to map a `Map` of `[language_code]->[description]`
- How to map [Internationalized data in Hibernate](http://relation.to/Bloggers/InternationalizedDataInHibernate) using a `UserType`
- [Implementing I18N relationships with JPA](http://blog.starmountsystems.com/implementing-i18n-relationships-with-jpa/)